# Get item’s metadata with Entity Framework?

Tags: sharepoint, entity-framework-4, sharepoint-2010

I'm working with Sharepoint 2010.

I need to know the date of creation/edition and the author/editor of items in my sharepoint's Lists, but I didn't find a solution to map these columns with Entity Framework.

I tried this kind of code :

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name = "tp_author", Storage = "_author", ReadOnly = true, FieldType = "User")]
public SPUser Author
{ 
    get 
    {
        return this._author;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!value.Equals(this._author))
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("Author", this._author);
            this._author = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Author");
        }
    }
}
```

But with that code, Sharepoint give me this error:

> Invalid transfer type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser

I also tried with other types for _author, but it doesn't change anything.

Is there a way to make this mapping?

Answer (score 1):

SPMetal generates the following code for a user field

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name="AssignedTo", Storage="_assignedToId", FieldType="User", IsLookupId=true)]
public System.Nullable<int> AssignedToId {
    get {
        return this._assignedToId;
    }
    set {
        if ((value != this._assignedToId)) {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("AssignedToId", this._assignedToId);
            this._assignedToId = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("AssignedToId");
        }
    }
}

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name="AssignedTo", Storage="_assignedTo", ReadOnly=true, FieldType="User", IsLookupValue=true)]
public string AssignedTo {
    get {
        return this._assignedTo;
    }
    set {
        if ((value != this._assignedTo)) {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("AssignedTo", this._assignedTo);
            this._assignedTo = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("AssignedTo");
        }
    }
}
```